# What is the tf.maximum equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, max

I am trying to find tf.maximum(X, Y) function equivalence in C++. Basically, what tf.maximum() does is "Returns the max of x and y (i.e. x > y ? x : y) element-wise."

If there is a library or a built-in function, I would like to use it.

I really want to find the fastest option for that except going through all the elements in a matrix or vector.

The main reason why I want to use a max function, I would like to replace any negative value item with 0 in a matrix or a vector in C++.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the exact data type of your matrix?

Comment: Data type is float. Essentially, I would like to replace any negative value item with zero in a matrix or a vector. That's why I am planning to use max function as in tensorflow.

Comment: What is the data type of the matrix object, not of the matrix element. std::vector of vectors? float**?

Comment: The object type is  half_float::half

Comment: It's the type of the elements, not the type of the matrix.

Comment: I have an array like defined as below:

half*array;

and it is populated as  array[i] = __float2half();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal C++ way of replacing values with other values is [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) and a function object

```
std::transform(thing.begin(), thing.end(), thing.begin(), [](float value) { return std::max(0, value); });
```

Comment: It throws an error like error : "auto" is not allowed here

Comment: Replace auto with float

Comment: What about a vector or a matrix filled with double values?

Comment: In C++14, you would be able to use `auto` where I had it in the first place, and it would be whatever `decltype(thing)::value_type` was (floats for `vector<float>`, doubles for `array<double, 100>` etc). Just use the contained type. You could instead write `struct non_negative{ template <typename Arithmetic> Arithmetic operator()(Arithmetic value) { return std::max(0, value); } };` in an appropriate scope. That's what an auto lambda expands to (the template parameter name is to give a hint as to what types are appropriate)

Comment: But basically you just want to match the type in the container